# OSX Migration Assistant seems to have ruined XCode 5 & 6. How to fix?

Tags: xcode

I had XCode 5 installed on my old Mac, with iOS6 & 7 simulators. On migrating to a new Mac (both running Mavericks) I now have XCode and XCode 5 installed, the former being XCode 6.x. I *think* XCode demanded to be upgraded because I wasn't using iOS8 previously, and on my old Mac XCode won't start without me letting it download updates.

Now, my XCode apps don't have simulators and when I installed them, things just don't work. XCode 5 launches simulators with a black screen even after resetting the simulator and force quitting, for example.

Is there a way to fix this or has everything just gone wrong and I should delete all the xcode apps and re-download/install?

I was previously targeting iOS 6/7 and while I'm happy to drop iOS6 support now, I'm unclear which XCode I should use.

Answer (score 0):

Open the App Store and check if your Xcode 6 is up to date.

I would recommend dragging each Xcode.app file to the trash and downloading a fresh install of Xcode 6 from the App Store.

Comment: I think it only just updated itself but it doesn't seem to list any simulators. The web seems full of XCode 6 problem stories with the beta version. Will v6 let me target iOS 7 (and even 6) or do I need to run 5 & 6 in parallel?

Comment: Xcode 6 includes the iOS 7 simulator.  For iOS 6 you still need Xcode 5.  A better question is why are you still supporting iOS 6?

Comment: Because quite a lot of people are still using it... or were when I last actively worked on the application! Probably you are right though, 1 version behind is enough.